# Cached loader got a known bad class error: Cassandra database and Apache OFBiz

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, ofbiz

I'm trying to get the OFBiz demo project off the ground with a Cassandra database.
After quite some struggle [i found this](http://ofbiz.135035.n4.nabble.com/How-to-integrate-Ofbiz-with-Cassandra-Database-td4682159.html) short guide on how to integrate those.

Following that, and using [this Cassandra jdbc driver](http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html) (cassandrajdbc1.1.jar) I get a bunch of exceptions thrown.

When running the project using `ant load-demo start` I get a lot of:
`org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: Cached loader got a known bad class name: org.apache.cassandra.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`

What could the issue be? Am I using the wrong jdbc driver or is it an OFBiz thing?

My `entityengine.xml` contents [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/eDR4H9Ka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Cached loader got a known bad class name` is thrown by OFBiz when the JDBC driver could not be found in the classpath.

In order to make sure that OFBiz finds the JDBC driver please copy the jar into the folder:

`framework/entity/lib/jdbc/`